# "Array to string conversion" error in Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently solved my previous question, but another problem came ...again.

It shows an error : **Array to string conversion**

Here's the code in model:

```
public function getKeterangan($id_kelas){
    $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('absensi a')
        ->join('siswa s', 'a.id_siswa = s.id_siswa')
        ->join('kelas k', 'a.id_kelas = k.id_kelas')
        ->where('a.id_kelas', $id_kelas);
    return $this->db->get()->result(); 
}
```

in controller :

```
foreach ($input['id_siswa'] as $key => $val) {
    $data = [
        'id_siswa' => $input['id_siswa'][$key],
        'id_mapel' => $input['id_mapel'],
        'id_kelas' => $input['id_kelas'],
        'time_in' => time(),
        'tanggal' => date("d"),
        'bulan' => date("m"),
        'tahun' => date("Y"),
        'keterangan' => $input['keterangan'][$key]
    ];
    $this->guru_m->saveAbsen($data);
}
```

in view

```
  <option value="<?= $keterangan; ?>" selected><?= $keterangan; ?> 
  </option>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with that code?

Comment: In the view put `<?php var_dump($keterangan); ?>` before your `select` and check if that variable isn't an array. If so, then you have to decide what value do you need. Otherwise, you'll see that error.

Comment: the result is array{0}

Comment: Make a scalar value from this array and you're done.

Comment: for example? I didn't know what you mean..

Comment: For example, `$keterangan = [3,4,5,6];`, then `<?= $keterangan[1]; ?>` will give you **4** as an output. `4` means a scalar value - `string` or `numeric`.

Comment: `$input['id_siswa'][$key]` is more simply written as `$val`.  This question Needs More Debugging Details.

Comment: We either need to see how your controller is passing data to the view, or what data is in `$keterangan`.  We don't need to see the `saveAbsen()` method at all.  The `select()` method can be omitted from your activerecord calls.  `result()` is an array of objects or an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$keterangan` variable in your view is an array, but you are using it as a value for the `<option>` tag. You need to either access a specific element of the array, such as `$keterangan[0]`, or use a loop to create multiple `<option>` tags for each element of the array like this:

```php
<select name="keterangan">
 <?php foreach ($keterangan as $item) { ?>
  <option value="<?= $item; ?>"><?= $item; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It is never necessary to repeat an option tag's text as its `value` attribute.  The `value` attribute declaration can be safely omitted.

Comment: Why advise the asker to unconditionally add "selected" to all options in the select tag?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for mentioning i forgot to remove it

Comment: yeah this is correct.. thank you Mehdi and Mickmackusa 